# Image links moving together

Tags: html, css

There is something I need help with. It already take me an hour or so and I still can't make it work. I have this in my `index.html` page:

```
<header>
    <img src = "Images/logo.png">
    <div id = "links">
        <a href = "http://www.facebook.com">
            <img src = "Images/fb.png" align = "middle" alt = "">
        </a>
        <a href = "http://www.twitter.com">
            <img src = "Images/twitter.png" align = "middle" alt = "">
        </a>
        <a href = "http://www.youtube.com">
            <img src = "Images/yt.png" align = "middle" alt = "">
        </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

Those link images are 64x64 pixels. I scaled them to 32x32 in my CSS. I want when I put mouse above specific image only that one to be enlarged, other should stay where they are.

First, I position div in right corner of header. That part is working as intended.

```
#links {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 38px;
    top: 12px;
}
```

Displaying images in 32x32 also working well.

```
div#links a img {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}
```

I have problem with this part:

```
div#links a:hover img {
height: 38px;
width: 38px;}
```

What is happening is all 3 images is moving on hover. I read many topics on this site and some others. First I was thinking it is because images aren't centered inside a div container. Tryied `vertical-align` along with `text-align` with no success. However, I was able to do centering images on center of div by using http://jsfiddle.net/B6Jsy/ and still all images moving on hover. What I think is happening is when one image is on hover and enlarged, others move from they position to center of div (div is resized). Just out of ideas how to deal with that.

I need some CSS sugestion how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Can you please post a demo?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/B6Jsy/769/

Comment: Further look at https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that when you hover over the `img`, the width will change and since those items are in their normal flow (not positioned absolutely for example), when you change the width of any of them, it's normal that the other icons will move.

To solve that, you can use CSS transforms like this:

```
div#links a:hover img {
   transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8n7L7dy2/)**